# Data Extension - Date record written

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I would like to know when each record in my Data Extension was inserted.

Is there is a system level way of doing that?

I'm aware that I can add a field to do this that will add the system date at the point the record is written.  I'm just wondering if I can access this data for an old Data Extension that doesn't contain such a field.

Comment: You have to have a field on the DE that handles this, there is no system field to be used

Answer (score 9):

If your data extension has a retention time, then each row gets  a hidden field that you can simply query with SQL or AMPScript: _CreatedDate.
At least in query studio you have to relabel the field to get a result, as "normal" DE fields aren't allowed to start with an underscore.

```
SELECT 
testField, 
[_CreatedDate] AS myCreatedDate
From yourDEWithRetention
```

My suspicion is that it's used in how record level data retention time is calculated internally, as it only works in DEs with retention.

Comment: Ooh!  Thanks for this tidbit!

Comment: This is fantastic!  Exactly the kind of answer we want to see on this board.

Comment: As a note on this as there is some misinformation being spread, although you can add retention to an existing DE that will create this field in the DE, the field will only show the current time that you added the retention as the created date, not the real date the record was created. So you will need to have the retention set before the record is added to have the true created date value in this field. Also it needs to be retention on individual records to have this field created.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to access the record level created date without using the trick you mentioned around the date field on the DE. Documenting below for those that aren't sure how to accomplish that.

By selecting the "use the current system date" option on the field attribute.

For example, while creating the DE, you can select it here:

[image: DE Creation]
If you have an existing DE, you can edit the attribute and select the option:

[image: Editing an Attribute]

This will result in the system date being written as the default value each time a new record is added:

[image: Record View]

Answer (score 0):

I have used Date selection as a current date but surprisingly it won't pick the system date its just record UTC time/date
[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/174636)