# Adding Fields in a Data Extension leads to resetting retention policy

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to add a 'CREATED_DATE' field  with a default value of current date, in my existing Data extension using wsproxy. The code runs fine and the fields gets added, however the data extension retention policy gets truned off(just resets). I am unsure of why this is happening. I have tried adding a non date field, a text field, but the output is same. I have to use wsproxy only, because I want to perform this operation in 30 business units. Below is my code:

The code below is adding a text field, since I was testing, but it behaves in the similar way when trying to add a date field.

```
 <script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1"); 
    //Configuration here
   var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var mid ="mid";

                   
                   var deKey = "DE_KEY"
                prox.setClientId({"ID": mid});
                  try{
                        var fields = [
                    {
                        "Name": "samplefield",
                        "FieldType": "text",
                        "IsPrimaryKey": false,
                        "IsRequired": false
                    }

                ];

                var result = prox.updateItem("DataExtension", {
                CustomerKey: deKey,
            Fields: fields
        });
        
        Write(Stringify(result));            
            }
                  catch(e)
          {
              Platform.Response.Write("Exception:" + Stringify(e));
          }
                                            

    prox.resetClientIds();   
   </script>
```

Comment: Sounds ugly. Not a solution, but: If your data extensions already have a Data Retention time, they should also have the hidden field _createdDate which contains exactly what your new field would provide.  See:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335400/data-extension-date-record-written/335417#335417

Then maybe the entire operation becomes unnecessary?

Comment: Hi @JonasLamberty, thank you for your comment, but the client wants to see when the data was created in the DE at any given time, using query. As the backend field is not available on the UI. On an another note,  the code should not behave the way it is, considering such uses cases of adding more fields to a DE are common.

Comment: Absolutely agree, this "shouldn't be".  Just saying.  `_createdDate` is reachable through queries. UI is another story.

Comment: We have tried using system fields in the queries in the past and it sometimes just fails intermittently, we want to avoid this and thus have a custom created_date field.